# Is it possible to edit a still image in Photoshop which is part of a sequence in Premier Pro?

Tags: premiere

I'm very new to Premier Pro, and I'm working on a project which encompasses some still artwork which I've created in Photoshop.  I'm finding that as I apply vignettes etc that I'm wanted to go back and tweak the original artwork in Photoshop from time to time to get the results I want.

What's the best way of doing this?  I've been exporting JPGs from Photoshop thus far and adding them to Premier.  Is it possible to avoid this and have the documents linked together so that I can edit the still frame which are part of my movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import Photoshop files to Premiere Pro, so that whatever change you make in the Photoshop file also appears in Premiere, like this:

Comment: Thanks so much, that's working great for me :-)